# What does 'demons in the snow' mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does 'demons in the snow' mean in the following context?

> The E30 generation 3-Series is a classic design that has yet to truly grow old. Many consider this generation of 3-Series to be the quintessential BMW. It is also a great car to learn how to drive in. Most are rear-wheel-drive and are equipped with a manual transmission, making them a true driving experience.
>
> There are all-wheel-drive variants available as well that are just **demons in the snow**. The engines are very reliable and once again, like the Mercedes, fairly inexpensive to repair.

www.businessinsider.com/best-first-cars-2012-1?op=?

Comment: In this context it means ‘the car is very nimble, controllable, maneuverable, can be driven aggressively’ In the snow

Comment: While I agree with Jim's understanding of the passage, I wanted to make clear that "demon" does not imply nimbleness, or controllability, or maneuverability. Those desirable qualities are invoked by the phrase that follows "demon", i.e. "demon *in the snow*".  For example, a politician could be said to be "a demon at the podium", and there the expression would mean that he was a very formidable opponent in a debate or a very formidable public speaker, a veritable "terror" with regard to those things in the political sphere at which he excelled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To say that someone is a demon in some context means that he has an ability bordering on the supernatural.  Horowitz was a demon on the piano.  Lionel Messi is a demon with the football.  Bobby Fischer was a demon at the chessboard.  Paul Bocuse is a demon in the kitchen.

By extension, a BMW is a demon in the snow, which has the meaning that Jim describes.  It seems like hyperbole to me in this case.